# What is the wrong with my ajax code.. Not going into the if statement

Tags: ajax

Please bear with me.. Im very new to ajax and getting some problem with my code
My code is as follows.. Im trying to get the response from my servlet and display it using alert .. can anyone let me know what is the problem with my code:

```
function checkempid(value) {
    var status = false;
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    var urlemp="postemployee";
    urlemp=urlemp+"?employeeId="+value;
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChangedemp ;
    xmlHttp.open("GET",urlemp,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);

    function stateChangedemp() { 
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){ 
            var showdata = xmlHttp.responseText;
            alert(showdata);

            **if(showdata=="Congratulations on your new account!"){
                alert("inside if");
                saveReportFinished(xmlHttp.responseText == 'complete');
            }**
            else{
                alert("inside else");
                saveReportFinished(false); 
            }
        }
    }

    function saveReportFinished(success) {
        if (success == true){
            status = true;
        }
        else {
            status = false;
        }
    }

    function GetXmlHttpObject(){
        var xmlHttp=null;
        try {
            xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        }

        return xmlHttp;
    }

    return status;
}
```

Please check out my if statement in bold. It never goes into the if statement. It always goes into else..Can anyone let me know what could be the problem???Thank You in advance.

Comment: Try an alert(showdata) in the else statement

Comment: What's the output of `alert(showdata);`?

Answer (score 0):

Now i would guess that that showdata never is "Congratulations on your new account!"  There might be whitespace, html formatting or whatever messing up what you try to do.

Better use the status code to detect whether the operation was okay (return "201 - created" if you can). Use 200 ("Ok") when you can't, any any of the client-error-codes when the account is not created.

If you can't use the status code, try to use xml or json encoding on the response, that can be parsed and leads to determernistic results

Comment: okay, I figured out that there were some white spaces.. But now i have a new problem... When I am trying to set the status which is a global variable to true or false inside SaveReportFinished function...it is not getting updated.. when I try to alert(checkempid()); it returns only the initial value always.. doesnt show the values inside SaveReportFinished.